# React: Design pattern that uses a Ref to set style of the parent component

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

I would like to ask if this is a sensible component design pattern in React.

Let's say I have the following components, App, ContentContainer and WithBlueBackground. The idea is to use a `Ref` to set a blue background on the ContentContainer with the WithBlueBackground component.

The simplified code would look something like this.

```
// App.js
export function App() => {
  const contentContainerRef = useRef();

  return (
    <ContentContainer contentContainerRef={contentContainerRef}>
      <WithBlueBackground contentContainerRef={contentContainerRef}>
      </WithBlueBackground>
    </ContentContainer>
  )
}
```

```
// ContentContainer
export function ContentContainer(props) => {
  return (
    <div ref={props.contentContainerRef}>
      // Some content     
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
// WithBlueBackground
export function ContentContainer(props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (props.containerRef && props.contentContainerRef.current) {
      props.contentContainerRef.current.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    }
  }, [props.contentContainerRef])

  return <>{ props.children }</>;
}
```

This way if I want to have a green background in the content container I can create a new component that sets this style without the ContentContainer having to know about this. This increases the composability of the code which is promote in the react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html).

Nevertheless, passing the refs is a bit ugly.

My question is, is this a sensible pattern and if not is there another way to achieve what I am trying to do here.

Comment: You are mutating props which should not be possible as they are per design read-only.

Comment: @Gh05d Uhmm, so you should not change the properties of a ref inside of child component?

Comment: If it is the parent, you could just pass an update function around to update the state of the parent which contains the color. Otherwise, use the context api.

Comment: @Gh05d ok great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a direct child, you could just pass an update function around:

```
// ContentContainer
export function ContentContainer(props) {
  const [backgroundColor, setColor] = React.useState("white");

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor }}>
      <ChildComponent setColor={color => setColor(color)}>// Some content</ChildComponent>;
    </div>
  );
}

// WithBlueBackground
export function ChildComponent(props) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    props.setColor("blue");
  }, []);

  return <>{props.children}</>;
}
```

If it is deeper nested, you could use the context API. The same principle applies.[enter link description here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)